# How to set size of centerText of pieChart

Tags: ios, ios-charts

I use library pod Charts.
I want to set size this but I don't know syntax this for set size.

```
chartView.centerText = "0"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
chartView.centerText = "0"
let centerText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "0")
            centerText.setAttributes([.font : UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size: 50)!,
                                      .paragraphStyle : paragraphStyle], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: centerText.length))
chartView.centerAttributedText = centerText;
```